# Infinitesimal Strain Tensor in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: mathematics, solid-mechanics

How can  I obtain the below formulas of infinitesimal strain in cylindrical coordinates using matrix calculation given the first formula? I find it hard to study them because I still don't know how to derive them.

$$
\epsilon_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\left(u\otimes\nabla+\nabla\otimes u\right)\\
\,\\
\begin{align}
u\otimes\nabla
&=\begin{bmatrix}u_r\\u_{\vartheta}\\u_z\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\\\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial U_r}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial U_r}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial U_r}{\partial z}\\\\\dfrac{\partial U_{\vartheta}}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial U_{\vartheta}}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial U_{\vartheta}}{\partial z}\\\\\dfrac{\partial U_z}{\partial r}&\dfrac{1}{r}\dfrac{\partial U_z}{\partial\vartheta}&\dfrac{\partial U_z}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}\end{align}
$$

Above, I show my try in deriving the first part of the tensor, but I didn't know how to derive the second part.

\begin{align}
     \varepsilon_{ij} &= \frac{1}{2} (U_{i,j} + U_{j,i})\\
    \varepsilon_{rr} & = \cfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} \\
    \varepsilon_{\theta\theta} & = \cfrac{1}{r}\left(\cfrac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta} + u_r\right) \\
    \varepsilon_{zz} & = \cfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial z} \\
    \varepsilon_{r\theta} & = \cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} + \cfrac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}- \cfrac{u_\theta}{r}\right) \\
    \varepsilon_{\theta z} & = \cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial z} + \cfrac{1}{r}\cfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial \theta}\right) \\
    \varepsilon_{zr} & = \cfrac{1}{2}\left(\cfrac{\partial u_r}{\partial z} + \cfrac{\partial u_z}{\partial r}\right) 
  \end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## differential derivation

The displacement vector is [defined as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_strain_theory#Strain_tensor_in_cylindrical_coordinates) :

$$\vec{u} = u_{r}\mathbf{\vec{e}_r} + u_{\theta}\mathbf{\vec{e}_\theta}+u_{z}\mathbf{\vec{e}_z} $$

by derivation you can obtain all the relevant strains.

## geometrical derivation

One way to derive the strain tensor is from geometry.

The diagonal (normal) components  $\epsilon_{rr}$ ,  $\epsilon_{θθ}$ , and  $\epsilon_{zz}$  represent the change of length of an infinitesimal element. The non-diagonal (shear) components describe the change of angles.

[image]

### normal strains

#### normal strain in radial direction $\epsilon_{rr}$

The change of length in the radial dimension is only due to displacement in the radial direction.

$$\epsilon_{rr} = \frac{ \left\{ u_r + \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} d r - u_r \right\} }{ d r} = \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r}$$

[image]

#### normal strain in circumerential direction $\epsilon_{\theta\theta}$

For the circumferential strain $ \epsilon_{θθ}$, there are two sources :

- due to radial displacement:
  $$\epsilon_{\theta\theta,r} = \frac{(r+u_r) d \theta - r d\theta}{r d \theta} = \frac{u_r}{r}$$
  i.e. if there is rotation and change in r, then the arc is greater for greater r, and smaller for smaller r
- to circumferential displacement
  $$\epsilon_{\theta\theta,c} = \frac{u_{\theta} + \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial \theta} d \theta - u_{\theta} }{r d \theta} = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}$$

This is the "rigid rotation" of a segment at the same radius.

[image]

So the total strain in the circumferential direction is:

$$\epsilon_{\theta\theta,r} = \frac{u_r}{r}+ \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}$$

#### $\epsilon_{r\theta}$

In the z direction, there is not much of a surprise. The derivation is exactly the same as in the cartesian coordinates. If the infinitesimal element increases by  $u_z$, then the strain is:

$$\epsilon_{zz} = \frac{\vartheta u_z}{\vartheta z}$$

### shear strains:

#### $\epsilon_{r\theta}$

This is equivalent the shear strain in xy coordinates in the sense that there is a change in shape of the component.

[image]

Again there are two components:

- for a change in angle with the side of the element parallel to the radial direction
  $$\frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r} - \frac{u_{\theta}}{r} \right] $$
- for a change in angle with the side of the element parallel to the circumerferntail direction
  $$ \frac{1}{2r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} $$

The total is:
$$\epsilon_{r \theta} = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r} - \frac{u_{\theta}}{r} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} \right]$$

#### $\epsilon_{r z}$

The strain on r,z of a infinitesimally small element can be derived more or less like the xz direction.

[image]

The new element has the same volume, but the angle between the edges initially parallel to r, and z have changed. For infinitesimally small angles:

$$ \epsilon_{rz} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial z}+ \frac{\partial u_z}{\partial r}\right)$$

#### $\epsilon_{r \theta}$

Similarly, for the shear strain in $r\theta $, if you imagine the plane which is perpendicular to the $rz$ plane at a specific radius (See image below for a representation), then the strain is again obtained as you would obtain any shear strain in a cartesian system.

[image]

$$\epsilon_{\theta z} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial u_z}{r \partial \theta} + \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial z}\right)$$